# Could not bind socket: Address already in use

Tags: debian, docker

I'm using port 8082 in dockerfile: `ENV FILESERVER_PORT 8082`.

When starting seafile with: 
`sudo bash /opt/seafile/seafile-server-6.3.4/seafile.sh start`

I get the error `http-server.c(2197): Could not bind socket: Address already in use`

I tried to delete `ccnet.sock` and starting docker again. That didn't work.

Netstat is showing:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8082  :::*      LISTEN      4993/docker-proxy            
tcp6       0      0 :::8090  :::*      LISTEN      5321/docker-proxy          
tcp6       0      0 :::8000  :::*      LISTEN      5007/docker-proxy
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306     0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN  899/mysqld
```

sudo docker ps:

```
#####:~$ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
############        mdh_seafile         "/bin/sh -c 'bash /s…"   23 minutes ago      Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8082->8082/tcp   mdh_seafile_1_f2341d904d27
############        mdh_owncloud        "/bin/sh -c 'bash /s…"   22 hours ago        Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:8090->80/tcp                             mdh_owncloud_1_260c3a56f2a5
############        mysql               "docker-entrypoint.s…"   26 hours ago        Up 3 minutes        3306/tcp, 33060/tcp                              mdh_db_1_46bebe733124
```

I tried changing the port in docker-compose from:

```
ports: 
    - "8000:8000" 
    - "8082:8082
```

to

```
ports: 
    - "8001:8001" 
    - "8083:8083
```

But it just told me the same.

Also netstat shows just one output:

```
sudo netstat -pna | grep 8082
tcp6     0    0 :::8082      :::*      LISTEN   19685/docker-proxy
```

Comment: Either change the port seafile is going to use, or change the port docker-proxy is using. You can't have 2 applications binding to the same port.

Comment: @Panki How do I find free ports I can use?

Comment: Run `netstat -lt` to see used tcp ports. Every port that is not used is free.

Comment: @RoVo Weird thing is when I change the ports in docker compose to 
` ports:    - "8001:8001"   - "8083:8083"  `

I still get the error `warning: seafile-controller not running. Have you run "./seafile.sh start" ?` and `Could not bind socket: Address already in use`